# Unable to start debugging on the web server. The web server could not find the requested resource

Tags: asp.net-mvc, debugging, iis

I'm having this error trying to debug my ASP.NET MVC app. I've set the app to "Use Local IIS Web server", and selected ASP.NET as the debugger. Running the site without debugging works just fine, but when I try to debug, I got this error:

```
Unable to start debugging on the web server. The web server could not find the requested source.
```

I'm using Visual Web Developer 2008 Express Edition.

Does anyone know how to fix this error? Thank you.

Comment: I've also seen this error when attempting to run/debug the app if the IIS website is not running.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to your web project's properties, then the "web" tab, then make sure that you're using the Visual Studio Development Server and not Local IIS or the custom webserver. I'm on VS2010 with Win7 and another developer was developing using a custom webserver URL and not the VS Dev Server

Comment: I'm in a situation where I can't use the VS Dev Server because I need a custom ISAPI rewriter. I'm able to keep the settings on IIS instead of VS Dev server, but then I get the error mentioned by OP. If I switch to VS Dev server, I can debug but I can't find my pages correctly since the ISAPI rewriter isn't included then. How can I debug while on IIS?

Comment: This fixes the issue for me as well, however I had been Deving for months under local IIS and debugging fine.  Recently installed VS 2012 SP1 and now it is happening, not sure if there is a correlation.

Comment: I have the same problem with the same Visual Web Developer 2008 Express Edition and I don't have any "Web" tab?  I also couldn't find it under debug - commands.  Is there some way to set it to display?

Answer (score 17):

For those encountering this with **Visual-Studio 2012** and/or **Windows 8** do the following.

You have to add .Net 3.5 (or 4.5) to your **Turn Windows Features on or off** window.  You get to it via :

> Control Panel -> Programs -> Turn Windows Features on or off

[image]

Click the `Asp.Net 3.5` and the  `Asp.Net 4.5` check box in the `IIS > WWW Service > Application Development Features` folder.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you are trying to develop on IIS and not iis express or development server.  If you are using asp.net mvc 4, make sure that the Application Pool is framework 4.  If not just make sure that your app pool it matches your asp.net mvc version.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, and i fixed this way:

Go to IIS Manager -> Go to the site -> Error Pages -> Actions: edit feature settings.. -> Make sure you checked "detailed errors for local requests and custom error pages for remote requests".

Comment: Well, this tip saves me tons of time. One of my colleauge encountered this problem for a year until I showed this solution. Thanks Gazza. By the way, how did you figure this out?

Answer (score 2):

IF you are using IIS6 and did the  add mapping for .* in IIS trick to get MVC working, when you added the .* handler to iisapi.dll you forgot to uncheck the "check the file exists" check box.[image]

Answer (score 1):

Also, be sure that the URL you're configuring in Visual Studio matches your Host Headers (Edit Bindings) in IIS.  This tripped me up for about an hour this morning before I realized my very stupid error.

Answer (score 0):

Having `maxRequestLength` or `maxAllowedContentLength` set to a ridiculously large or small value will also trigger this error.

Answer (score 0):

What i did, was just type the IP address in the web tab instead of "localhost"

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me today. Turned out to be that the default website was stopped in iis. I had been working on a second website that didn't use it for a long time. Simple fix but took me a while to see it!

Answer (score 0):

The root cause for this error can often be that the Windows Service W3SVC is not started. Check that this service in Windows Services console (services.msc) is started. In IIS you will now see the the Start icon is greyed out. This means that the W3SVC service is running.