# Windows 10/IIS 10: Unable to start debugging on the web server. The web server could not find the requested resource

Tags: silverlight, iis, http-status-code-404, iis-10

I recently got a new laptop with windows 10 pre-installed which comes with IIS 10.
Now I'm having trouble debugging two of my older web application (one of them in silverlight, the other one a WebApi project).

When debugging the application I get the following error in VisualStudio:

> Unable to start debugging on the web server. The web server could not find the requested resource.

When browsing to the application from IIS i get the following error with regards to the silverlight application (the WebAPI project shows no errors):

> HTTP Error 404.4 - Not Found The resource you are looking for does not
>   have a handler associated with it.

When I compared the IIS settings of my new laptop to the settings on my old laptop and the laptop of a collegae who recently upgraded from win7->win10 (on both we can succesfully debug the silverlight application) we found that my new laptop had far fewer handler mappings registred in IIS. We are still unsure if this is the cause of the error and if so, which handler mappings would be needed for silverlight.
These missing handler mappings looked like aspnet was incorrectly installed so we ran the following command in de dev console (as admin):

dism /online /enable-feature /all /featurename:IIS-ASPNET45
(this seems to be the equivalent of aspnet_regiis, which does not work anymore for win10)

This did not fix my issue and also did not add any handler mappings in IIS.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14711807/the-web-server-could-not-find-the-requested-resource-visual-studio-debugging) and [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3816667/unable-to-start-debugging-on-the-web-server-the-web-server-could-not-find-the-r) SO question and also tried:

- checking the ISAPI and CGI restrictions (4 entries, all set to allow)
- checking that the ASP.NET 3.5 and ASP.NET 4.6 features are turned on
  under IIS in windows features (are both turned on)
- removing any
  .csproj.user files (not present)
- completely removing iis and re-enabling it
- setting the apppool to allow running 32bit applications (on a 64bit machine)
- checking whether I have "url scan" installed, for as far as I know, I don't.
- debugging with iis express, which works for the WebApi application but does not work for the silverlight application
- checking whether the site in IIS was "started"
- typing my ipaddress instead of localhost in the debugging url

Any help/insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you checked the windows event viewer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the silverlight application it turns out, in trying to get the solution to work on my machine I had added a "clear" in the "handlers" section of my web.config

```
 <handlers>
      <clear/> <-- culprit
      <add name=.....
```